# Changes to Series[...] in version 11.1

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

I have updated to Mathematica 11.1 and I am shocked to see that the `Series` function now works differently:

If I enter

```
Series[x^2+x^3, {x,0,0}]
```

it will return

```
x^2+O[x]^3
```

which is just weird. In the old versions, it would correctly return

```
O[x]^2
```

I get that it now tries to return the leading non-trivial term, but this "feature" breaks a number of functions that I have written over the last years and use in my daily work. Does anybody know if there is a quick way to make Series work as it used to in older versions? Did anybody actually see this in any changelog? Because I for sure haven't...

Cheers,
Matthias

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: You should report this to Wolfram and let us know what they said.

Comment: Already did. I'm just hoping someone else has encountered it and found some quick workaround... I'll let you guys know what the reply is as soon as I get one.

Comment: btw: *Mathematica* hasn't released a comprehensive "changelog" since the last 10 years.

Comment: What is the `FullForm` of the desired answer?

Comment: @jjc385 Most probably `SeriesData[x, 0, List[], 2, 2, 1]`

Comment: @QuantumDot: Yes, this is exactly what it should give. Concerning the changelog, this is the closest it gets: [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn111.html). It lists functions that were added or updated - Series is however not on that list.

Comment: The reference page for Series in the Documentation center gives no indication the function was changed in version 11.1.  To the contrary, it states last update as being in 1996 (version 3.0).

Comment: Also a bit weird, although not actually wrong, is that the output from `Series[x^2 + x^3, {x, 0, 3}]` is `x^2 + x^3 + O[x]^4` when the exact value ought to be simply `x^2 + x^3`.

Comment: @MatthiasKoenig Did Wolfram reply anything to you? This unexpected behavior of Series badly breaks some of my packages and I'm quite surprised that this is still not fixed (e.g. via paclet updates) :(

Comment: The only reply I got was "I'll forward this to the devs". Nothing since then. The update that was rolled out shortly after also didn't fix it. Right now I'm using QuantumDot's reply. I suggest everyone affected submits a bug report to keep up the pressure on that matter.

Comment: @MatthiasKoenig I see. QuantumDot's workaround is surely very nice, but for research results I'd like to be 99.99% sure that things work as they should, without having to rely on undocumented functions and similar tricks. `Series` is such an essential function of Mathematica, that IMHO it simply cannot be broken like this in a production release.

Comment: As of version 11.2, the bug is fixed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an undocumented function `` System`SeriesDump`truncateSeries `` that you can use to facilitate the truncation of your series.

```
System`SeriesDump`truncateSeries[Series[x^2 + x^3, {x, 0, 0}], {x, 0, 0}]
(* O[x]^2 *)
```

Modify the `Series` function so that it calls `` System`SeriesDump`truncateSeries `` after it is applied:

```
ClearAttributes[Series, Protected];
Series[expr_, {var_, x0_, nf_}] := 
  Block[{$inSeries = True, result},
    result = System`SeriesDump`truncateSeries[
      Series[expr, {var, x0, nf}], {var, x0, nf}];
    result] /; ! TrueQ[$inSeries];
SetAttributes[Series, Protected];
```

Then,

```
Series[x^2 + x^3, {x, 0, 0}]
(* O[x]^2 *)
```

All disclaimers associated with using undocumented functionality and modifying built-in functions apply.

Comment: It's a good workaround, undocumented notwithstanding.

Comment: `Unprotect[]`/`Protect[]` is the traditional way to remove and restore the `Protected[]` attribute, but this apparently works, too.

Comment: Incredible, thanks a lot.

Comment: I just wanted to add that *Series* in 11.0.0 does not consistently return the leading order term.
Mathematica 10.0.0 evaluates Series[(-(h^3*t1^3)/864 + (h*t1)^(3/2) - (h^4*t1^3*t2) 373248 + (h*(h*t1)^(3/2)*t2)/864 + (h^2*(h*t1)^(3/2)*t2^2) 746496)^(1/6), {h, 0, 2}] to
$$
\sqrt[4]{h} \sqrt[6]{\text{t1}^{3/2}}+\frac{h^{5/4}\sqrt[6]{\text{t1}^{3/2}} \text{t2}}{5184}-\frac{h^{7/4}\left(\text{t1}^{3/2}\right)^{7/6}}{5184}+O\left(h^{9/4}\right)
$$
while 11.0.0 returns
$$
\sqrt[6]{h^{3/2} \text{t1}^{3/2}}+\frac{h \text{t2} \sqrt[6]{h^{3/2} \text{t1}^{3/2}}}{5184}-\frac{h^{3/2} \left(\text{t1}^{3/2}

Comment: @Cobi Ok, I've moved it here, let's hope you will get feedback from QD :)

Comment: @Cobi I believe the reason for the difference is that `Series` is no longer effectively applying `PowerExpand` since that can lead to erroneous results.  To recover pre-11.1 `Series` behavior, apply `PowerExpand` and `Series` again:    `Series[PowerExpand[Normal[Series[expr,{h,0,2}],h]],{h,0,2}]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Are you guys planning to fix it via a paclet update or should we wait for another Mathematica release? I mostly use Mathematica for symbolic HEP/QFT calculations and there `Series` is one of the most essential functions (e.g. for expansions in masses, external momenta etc.). If `Series` is not working properly there, then this is really bad...

Comment: @vsht It's fixed for the next release.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I see, thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for **expansions in one variable only**.  It would need to be extended for multiple variables.

---

If you're looking for a quick and dirty fix, you might replace every instance of `Series` in your code with `series` :

```
ClearAll[series]
series[f_, {x_, x0_, nMaxSpec_}, args___] := (
  Series[f, {x, x0, nMaxSpec}, args]
   // Replace[ 
    HoldPattern@SeriesData[x, x0, coeffs_, n0Min_, n0Max_, denom_] :>
     With[{nMin = n0Min/denom, nMax = n0Max/denom},
      SeriesData[x, x0, {}, n0Min, n0Min, denom]
       /; ! n0Min === n0Max && n0Min > nMaxSpec
      ]
    ]
  )
```

As mentioned above, this works for expansions in one variable only.  It would need to be extended for multiple variables.

It would probably be ideal to modify the behavior of `Series` itself rather than have to replace it with a different function.  I attempted to do such a thing, but I was unsuccessful.  Perhaps someone more clever will figure out something better.