# Change in behaviour of Series from 11.1

Tags: series-expansion

In 11.0,

```
Series[(1 - Sqrt[1-4z])/2, {z, 1/4, 1}]
```

gives

```
1/2 - I Sqrt[z-1/4] + O[z-1/4]^(3/2)
```

as one would expect. From 11.1 (and still in 11.3), the output is

```
(1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[1-4z]) + O[z-1/4]^2
```

Even worse,

```
SeriesCoefficient[(1 - Sqrt[1-4z])/2, {z, 1/4, 0}]
```

now returns `1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[1-4z]` which is nonsense, rather than the correct answer of `1/2`. Similarly,

```
SeriesCoefficient[(1 - Sqrt[1-4z])/2, {z, 1/4, 1/2}]
```

now gives `0` rather than `-I`.

This is presumably related to *[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143414/changes-to-series-in-version-11-1)*, but is not yet fixed and seems like a more fundamental failure in the handling of Puiseux series to me.

This has broken a lot of code I regularly use.

Comment: Getting `Series` to behave at branch points has been something of a challenge. The issues indicated here have been addressed, although obviously not in time for version 11.3. My apologies for any inconveniences this may have caused.

Comment: This appears to be a relative of the issue from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156808/series-expansion-wrong/156818#comment450034_156818) and others linked to in a comment there.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for the update; glad to know a fix is on its way; I'll keep using 11.0 until 11.4 appears.